# How can I have drivers active in only certain frames?

Tags: drivers

Driver active for certain frames
I have a character playing a saxophone. His fingers are driven by drivers which 
get they input from the keys of the saxophone. At the end of the music I would 
like the hands to be moved freely, for the character to wave at the audience for example. 
How can I disable the action of the drivers after or before a certain frame?
Thanks for any help.
Daniel

Hi atomicbezierslinger, thanks for your reply. First my background: I am a retired computer hardware technician with programming knowledge in Turbo Pascal and VB. I am new to Blender, this is my first project and have very little knowledge in Python.
The project: three frogs made of bits of metal, plastic tubes, springs and hands made of rubber gloves are playing three instruments, a vibraphone, a guitar and a saxophone. Picture 1
[image]
Picture 1 ........................................................... Picture 2

For the vibraphone I have a cube that I have keyed frame  using 
a CSV file in order to have a reference for the music. All the poses were then entered manually one by one. For the guitar as the right hand only needed three different poses and the left one five, I also used the cube key frames to know where to copy the poses.
But for the saxophone (picture 2) I am using a very different approach. Only seven fingers are used to play the instrument so by using CSV files, seven bones are animated. They move in the Y location from 7 to 8 according to the musical notes. Bones are named SCtrl.Bone.1  to 7, starting at the top of the picture.

. Every key on the saxophone as well as every valve have a single driver assigned to its Z rotation. This is the mechanical part of the saxophone. 
Picture 3 - key pressed - valve closed
Picture 4 - key released - valve open

The fingers of the character are animated with the same technique. The Z rotation of the second bone, starting at the finger tip, is modified by a driver using the Y position of the bones SCtrl.Bone.1 to 7.
Picture 5 - driver settings 
After your reply I have noticed that I could add a modifier, bottom part of picture 5, in the driver panel with ‘Restrict Frame Range’ and ‘Use Influence’ but no luck. I found on the internet that this was reported as a bug in October 2013 Blender 2.67. But apparently it is not yet fixed or I am not using this correctly. What can I do to have the driver only working at certain frames. I was thinking of entering the frame range in the expression but this would not disable the driver. Any idea ? 
NB: I could not place the pictures where I wanted as I am only allowed two pictures. Sorry for that.
[image]

Comment: Is the driver modifying a value of a armature modifier?  Please provide more screen images and a more detailed description.

Comment: Hi, I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Assuming modifiers are used.
You can keyframe animate the [influence].

Above the [Copy Rotation] modifier has an influence value which is keyframed.

Influence can range between 0 and 1 as a floating point value.
0 is no strength. 1 is full strength.  .5 is middle strength.

The incomplete [IK] modifier has an influence value as well.

The frame number can be known from a driver.  The single value is #frame.

Keyframes are a common way of animating influence because they can be seen in the Graph Editor.  The graph editor is visual and you can easily express [ease in] and [ease out] by the  [influence] value thus achieving smooth transitions of movements.

Objects and Data can have a [custom property] value in the range 0 to 1 as well.  So a copied driver for multiple objects can refer to that property.

---

Secondary because we do not have details on the question.

You might have some pseudo python statement

if frame > 22 and frame < 88 do something

//pseudo less manageable less esirable

Something better might be

if mycustompropertyinfluence > 0 do something(mycustompropertyinfluence)

//pseudo and more visually manageable more desirable

If Blender can express this via user interface no new python might be desirable.